# How to calculate the distributionderivatives of abs(x)?

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Lets say we have $f(x) = |x|$.

I want to calculate $f'$ and $f''$, how would  I go about this?

I understand that this is not defined at $x = 0$, so it will have to be done in two steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for a thorough understanding of distributions, it is necessary at the beginning (and sometimes a long time after, when faced to tricky situations) to stick to the definitions, in the following way.

Let $T=[f]$ denote the distribution associated with *locally integrable* function $f$. Then for any $\varphi$ in the set of infinitely derivable  functions with compact support:

$\langle T',\varphi\rangle=-\langle T,\varphi'\rangle =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x| \varphi'(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^0(-x)\varphi'(x)dx+\int_0^{\infty}x\varphi'(x)dx$

Then integrate by parts,

$-\int_{-\infty}^0\varphi(x)dx+\int_0^{\infty}\varphi'(x)dx=<-1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{-}} ,\varphi>+<+1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{+}} ,\varphi>$

giving:

$$< T', \varphi> \ = \ <-1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{-}}  +1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{+}} ,\varphi>$$

i.e.,

$$ T'=-1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{-}}  +1 \ on \ \mathbb{R_{+}}$$

Otherwise said: $[f]'(x)=2H(x)-1$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

Thus, more directly, $f''(x)=2\delta \ \ (1)$ because of the jump of intensity +2 in $0$.

(see math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.303/delta-notes.pdf).

A good exercise would be to establish (1) using definitions like done for the first derivative.

Comment: Thank you, @Pedro, I will memorize this $\langle$ and $\rangle$ for the next time...

Comment: Hi @JeanMarie Could I ask you something about the fourier transform of |x| ?

Comment: Yes but I will be able to answer you some time later.

Comment: Does it hold that the Fourier transform of |x| is equal to $-\frac{4 \pi}{\xi^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

To compute the second derivative, you have to express
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}|x|·φ''(x)dx
$$
in terms of the values of any test function $φ\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)$. Indeed this is done via partial integration on the half-axes.
$$
\int_0^∞ x·φ''(x)dx = [x·φ']_0^∞-\int_0^∞ φ'(x) dx=φ(0),
$$
and 
$$
\int_{-∞}^0 (-x)·φ''(x)dx = -[x·φ']_{-∞}^0+\int_{-∞}^0 φ'(x) dx=φ(0).
$$

Comment: Does it hold that the Fourier transform of |x| is equal to  $\frac{4 \pi}{\xi^2}$ ?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/absT.php where they find $-1/(2 \pi^2 f^2)$ with the following definition of F.T. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} df \varphi(t)exp(-2i\pi*f*t)$ ? But there is a much shorter path; it suffices to consider $|x|=x sign(x)$. thus, mult. by $-2i \pi$ LHS an RHS, giving $-2i\pi |x|=(-2i\pi x)sgn(x)$. Taking F.T. : $-2i \pi FT(|x|)=vp(\frac{1}{i \pi f}) \ $ thus $ \ FT(|x|)=\frac{1}{-2 i \pi } \frac{1}{i \pi } PV(\frac{1}{f})'$ where prime = derivative. Conclusion $FT(|x|)=\frac{1}{2 \pi^2 }(-FP(\frac{1}{f^2}))$ (PV = Principal Value, FP= Finite Part)

Comment: @evinda Is my answer satisfying ?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f$ is a distribution defined, for any test function $\phi$, by $\langle f',\phi\rangle=-\langle f,\phi'\rangle$.

$-<f,\phi'>=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|\phi'(x)dx=-\left(\int_{-\infty}^{0}-x\phi'(x)dx+\int_0^{+\infty}x\phi'(x)dx\right)$

Integrating by parts, we get:

$\left[x\phi(x)\right]_{-\infty}^0-\int_{-\infty}^0\phi(x)dx-\left[x\phi(x)\right]_{0}^{+\infty}+\int_0^{+\infty}\phi(x)dx$

As $\phi$'s support is compact, we obtain $<H(x),\phi>-<H(-x),\phi>$ where $H$ is the heaviside distribution:

$$<H,\phi>=\int_0^{+\infty}\phi(x)dx$$

Then, knowing that the derivative of $H$ is $\delta$, you can compute $f''$.